# Oración condicional contrafactual (negada mediante "no")

Tags: subjuntivo, negación

> No lo habría creído *si ella misma **no** se lo hubiera contado.*

Tal vez me esté equivocando pero ¿puede ser que la negación "no" en la oración subordinada transfiera la perspectiva de irreal a real? Se lo contó, entonces se trata de una acción que sucedió en el pasado. ¿O no?...

Comment: No creo que sea un tema de "perspectiva" o de qué es real y qué no. Básicamente dice "si lo hubiese contado otra persona, yo no lo habría creído" o lo que es lo mismo "De no ser por este hecho (que ella misma lo contó) no lo habría creído". No sé si entiendo bien qué te causa confusión?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las condicionales contrafactuales se caracterizan por que la realidad fáctica contradice la prótasis (condición) y la apódosis (resultado), de modo que lo que realmente ocurrió puede expresarse por sendas cláusulas en el sentido opuesto: si la condición o el resultado son afirmativos, la realidad se expresa en negativo, y si son negativos, la realidad se expresa en afirmativo.

- Lo habría creído (afirmativo) si ella se lo hubiera contado (afirmativo).

La realidad es que ella **no** se lo contó y, en consecuencia, él **no** lo creyó.

La oración en cuestión tiene ambas cláusulas (la principal y la condicional) en negativo. Por lo tanto, la realidad se expresa mediante el afirmativo:

- No lo habría creído si ella misma no se lo hubiera contado.

La realidad es que ella **sí** se lo contó y, por lo tanto, él **sí** lo creyó.

También podemos encontrar casos que combinan afirmativo y negativo en la contrafactual: la situación real se expresará en el sentido contrario.

- Lo habría creído si ella no le hubiera insistido (pero ella le insistió y él no lo creyó, pues desconfiaba de su insistencia).
- No lo habría creído si ella le hubiera insistido (pero ella no le insistió y él lo creyó).

Comment: ¡¡¡Una explicación perfecta!!! Muchísimas gracias =)

Answer (score 2):

Me encantó la explicación de Gustavson.
Solo quiero añadir que las conjugaciones verbales usadas en los ejemplos nos dan la pauta para que la oración sea contrafactual. Cabe mencionar algunos casos:

1. No todas las construcciones de prótasis y apódosis nos llevan a una situación contrafactual

> Si vienes mañana, te lo cuento.
>   Si viniera hoy, le diría que me gusta

2. Para ser considerada contrafactual la prótasis debe estar en pretérito pluscuamperfecto del subjuntivo; es decir, un hecho que ya no tiene posibilidad de revertirse.

> Si hubieras venido más temprano, lo hubieras visto.
>   No lo hubiese creído si mis ojos no lo hubiesen visto.

3. Se puede obviar cualquier parte de la construcción.

> ¡Caray! No lo hubiera creído...
>   Si tan solo me lo hubiera contado antes...

Comment: Desearía agregar a tu comentario que el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo también puede utilizarse en contrafactuales del tipo: *Si fuera multimillonario - de hecho no lo soy - me compraría esa mansión*.

Comment: @Krauss: Muchas gracias =)